# Finding all subsets of a set, Powerset, recursively by cloning n-1 and adding n to the clones

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

Having the set {a,b,c} I want find all the subsets in recursive manner. **I have already solved this problem using bitmasking** but I want to understand the way that a person stated in this youtube video [here](https://youtu.be/rEJzOhC5ZtQ?t=2751)

There are other stackoverflow threads about this problem but I have not found any that are solving the way she states in the video, she says,

**"take the subsets of a and b, clone them and then add c to all the clones"**

I am having trouble picturing the "simple" recursive method that would accomplish this. Is the recursive method, once exhausted, have all the subsets of A,B and the clones of A,B (duplicates at this point) and then propagates back up adding C to only the clones?

In other words, I start with a for loop on the set, I call my recursive function, I then do a for loop of n-1 and call my recursive method in that for loop, I cannot see how I can get C to be added to already existing subset clones in an array that is being built with recursion.

```js
    function SubsetBuilder(set) {
        this.set = set;

    }

    SubsetBuilder.prototype.getSubsetsRecursive = function () {

        //Set = {a,b,c} 
        //take the subsets of a and b, clone them and then add c to all the clones
        //subsets of {a,b}=
        //{}
        //{a}
        //{b}
        //{a,b}
        var n = this.set.length;
        var result = [];
        
        var recurseForSubsets = function (prefix, index) {
            for (var i = index; i < n -1; i ++) {
                result.push(prefix + this.set[i]);
                recurseForSubsets(prefix + this.set[i], i + 1);
            }
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            recurseForSubsets("", j);
        }

        return result;
    }

    SubsetBuilder.prototype.printSubsets = function () {
        var self = this;

        if (!self.set)
            return;

        var n = this.set.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < (1 << n) ; i++) {
            var subset = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (((i >> j) & 1) === 1) { // bit j is on
                    subset.push(this.set[j]);
                }
            }
            console.log(subset);
        }
    }

    var set = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var obj = new SubsetBuilder(set);
    //obj.printSubsets();
    console.log(obj.getSubsetsRecursive());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this a try and came up with

```
function getSubsets(inp) {
  if (inp.length == 1) {
      // return the single item set plus the empty set
      return [inp, []];
  } else {
      var e = inp.pop();
      var s = getSubsets(inp);
      // duplicate the elements of s into s1 without creating references.  
      // this might not be the best technique
      var s1 = s.concat(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s)));
      // add e to the second group of duplicates
      for (var i=s.length; i < s1.length; i++) {
          s1[i].push(e);
      }
      return s1;
  }    
}

var set = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var list = getSubsets(set);
console.log(list);

// result
//  [["a"], [], ["a", "b"], ["b"], ["a", "c"], ["c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

The lady in the video said that all subsets of `{a,b,c}` can be formed from taking all the subsets of `{a,b}` and appending `c` to each one.  Not entirely accurate (a valid subset of `{a,b,c}` does not have to include `c`), but a starting place for the algorithm.  I changed the rule to all subsets of `{a,b,c}` can be formed from taking two copies of the subsets of `{a,b}` and appending `c` to each element of the second copy.

I think I could get rid of or simplify the `if`, because essentially the second block of code does the same as the first, so it's not ideal.

To me it makes sense that the algorithm runs in `O(2^n)` because the results vary in the same way (3 elements in the input array = 2^3 elements in the output array) - you might have to forgive my use of JSON to assume that complexity though.  I'd find a better way to deep clone the array, even so, that might add more complexity.

Comment: Thanks I am studying this, will reply soon, good job outta you

Comment: This is great, I wish I knew your thought processes better for how you came up with this solution, I understand your code comments but I wonder why I could not figure the solution on my own, perhaps its as simple as an is of IQ

Comment: Would the complexity of this be O(2^n)?

Comment: @BrianOgden I hope I've explained myself a little in the answer.

Comment: You did thanks, I get it, I just wish I could have come up with it on my own, thanks for your help, if you have done complexity analysis lately, would be so kind as to tell if this algorithm is O(n^2)?